# How to limit concurrent connections from client in Golang GRPC

Tags: go, concurrency, grpc

I'm a newbie in GRPC.

I have a task:
I have to implement a service in Golang GRPC.

Service with functions:

1. Accepts image from client and saves them.
2. Shows a list of saved images.

Question is how to limit conccurent connections from client:

to download/save files(images) - 10 conccurent requests.

to get list of saved messages - 100 conccurent requests.

Comment: Connections can be reused, so "concurrent connections" != "concurrent requests" (unless your client always connects, makes request, disconnects). What do you want to happen when the limit is hit? Assuming you mean "concurrent requests", the simplest technique may well be to maintain a counter (protected by a `Mutex` or similar) in your implementation and just return a suitable error if the limit has been hit.

Comment: @Brits Yes what I mean are concurrent requests only 10 calls can be made at a time to save files and only 100 calls to get list of that files. If there are only 10 requests being made I will return error message with status code ABORTED or UNAVAILABLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your comments it looks like you just want to check how many in-progress calls there are to a specific RPC function. You can do this with standard Go functionality (the same approach can be used for any function). For example; as a counter to your service struct:

```
type Server struct { ...
 ...
  downloadCount atomic.Int32
 ...
}
```

Then use that when processing the call:

```
func (s *Server) Download(context context.Context, *pbpkg.DownloadRequest) (*pbpkg.DownloadRequest, error){
   inProgressCount := downloadCount.Add(1)
   defer downloadCount.Add(-1) // decrease counter when done

   if inProgressCount  > 10 {
      return nil, status.Errorf(codes.ResourceExhausted, "Download limit hit")
   }
   // Do stuff here
}
```

Note that I've used `atomic.Int32`; there are other approaches (`sync.Mutex`, `chan` etc) but it is important that you consider race conditions.

I'm sure there are other approaches ([e.g.](https://github.com/platinummonkey/go-concurrency-limits)) but often the simple approach is best!

Comment: Yes seems like it solves the task I'm trying to do. I will check it later thank you.